# Unity: Understand how "Raycast Target" in UI components works

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to under how "Raycast Target" option works. I think the it works is

1. if this is checked, then my UI element will consume the mouse/touch events and any 3D object behind it will not get the mouse/touch event.
2. If Unchecked, this will pass the mouse event to 3D object behind it.

but his is not how it is behaving.

I have a UI text on canvas and a 3D cube gameobject behind it.I have added following script on UI text

```
public class CaptureUIObjectEvent : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("In UI click event");
    }
}
```

I have added following script on 3D object

```
public class Capture3DObjectEvent : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log("In 3D click event");
    }
}
```

**When "Raycast Target is checked"** : Both the UI text and 3D object is capturing the event. So both the logs are printed. The UI text is not blocking the click event. I think this is not the correct behavior. Also the 3D object event log is printed first. I think Unity has multiple default raycaster in scene for UI (**graphics raycaster**) and 3D (**Physics raycaster**) objects. Is it so? Is this behavior expected then and does this mean my 3D object will get the mouse click always?

**When "Raycast Target is Unchecked"** : Only 3D object is getting clicked. This is expected I think.

I have to make the CaptureUIObjectEvent  derive from IPointerClickHandler to make it capture any event but for 3D object I dont have to use that. I thibk this is also because of different raycaster used by UI and 3D objects. Is it so?

This is my scene
[image]

Comment: @Programmer: The question you mentioned does not explain why "Raycast Target" when checked does not block the event

Comment: Are you sure you don't have both raycasters (a graphic one and a physic one) in your scene? That would explain why your cube gets the mouse click event.

Comment: That answers answers this *"Is this behavior expected then and does this mean my 3D object will get the mouse click always?"* If you want blocking to work, don't mix `OnPointerClick` and `OnMouseDown`. Use `OnMouseDown` for all your Objects. That answer provided a proper way to actually detect click on any type of object which should solve your problem.

Comment: When I have "OnMouseDown" in UI elements, I am not able to get any click event on UI items whether my "Raycast Target" is checked or not. Can you please what mistake I may be making. I am able to get click event when I use "OnPointerClick"

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo when I said *"Use OnMouseDown for all your Objects."*. I meant to say use `OnPointerClick` and `OnPointerDown` for all your Objects. See #6 and #7 from the duplicated answer on how to make this work on 2D and 3D objects. You can also find other functions to use from that post.